# Change two different date formats in a data frame column

Tags: r

I have a data frame which includes a date column. However, I have some dates that are formatted in one way and others in another. How can I adjust this data into a single date format. How can I deal with date variables which look as follows.

```
    df = data.frame(Date=c("5/1/13","8/1/13","9/1/13","Apr-10",
              "Apr-11","Apr-12","Apr-13"))
```

For what it's worth, my data really looks as follows:

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   425376 obs. of  27 variables:
 $ Date                     : chr  "Jan-10" "Jan-10" "Jan-10" "Jan-10" ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more information. In the "`/`" dates, which number corresponds to year, month and day respectively? In the `-` dates, does the number correspond to year or day? Which guess do you want to make about the component that is missing? Please also show us the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I would use `lubridate` and `parse_date_time` to convert dates.

But The `"%b-%y"` format is impossible to parse ( as.Date, strptime fails too). I had to add a day to convert it to `%d-%b-%y` format. Here my code:

```
df$Date <- as.character(df$Date)
format = guess_formats(df$Date,orders=c('dmy','my'))
df$Date[format== "%b-%y"] <- paste(1,df$Date[format== "%b-%y"],sep="-") 
parse_date_time(df$Date,"dmy")
[1] "2013-01-05 UTC" "2013-01-08 UTC" "2013-01-09 UTC" 
    "2010-04-01 UTC" "2011-04-01 UTC" "2012-04-01 UTC" "2013-04-01 UTC"
```